# how can i put columns under each other on mobile but side by side on pc?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the columns to line up neatly on mobile and on PC 3 above and 3 below I can't do this, can someone help?

i tried to use @media in css which didn't work and it came out looking weird

Comment: _i tried to use @media in css which didn't work_ Can we see it in [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I understand, I remember that I had exactly the same problem one day working on a practice project.

what you need to do is to use *flexbox* beside media queries if you know working with flexbox, it's super easy with flexbox otherwise it gets a bit complicated by just css but still possible to get it done just by CSS.
so what you need to do is to:

1: give display **flex** to the container.

```
.container{
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

2: **flex-wrap** should have the value of **wrap**.

3: set your desire width to the items with percentage ( % ) in media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
      /* Phones */
      .items{
           width: 100%;
       }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 900px){
      /* Tablets & Laptops*/
      .items{
           width: 50%;
       }
}
```